# Modernizer conditional load of polyfill

Tags: modernizr

I am using a javascript library that uses CustomEvent that doesnt seem to be fully supported in Android 4.1. So I thought I'd use Modernizer to conditionally load a CustomEvent polyfill in browsers where it is missing.

- I went here: https://modernizr.com/download?customevent-dontmin
- Selected 'CustomeEvent',
- Downloaded the suggested EventListner.js polyfill,
- Pressed 'Build' and downloaded the custom Modernizer.
- I added to my index.html: `<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>`
- And added this to my javascript:

  Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.customevent,
    nope: 'EventListener.js'
  });

But I get an error: `TypeError: Modernizr.load is not a function`

Can someone please confirm I've not gone completely off piste here and I'm using modernizer correctly? And do I have to download another script or something to get the Modernizer.load function? (Modernizer seems to have changed since similar questions were asked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modernizr.load was removed from Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/news)

> Modernizr.load has been deprecated in favor of using yepnope.js directly; from v3.0, yepnope.js must be included in the page in order for Modernizr.load to work: calling .load() will simply pass the arguments on to yepnope(); this will be removed fully in a future release (#1241)